# Is Three.js Normal Map Shader Computing Lighting In Tangent Space?

Tags: three.js

I was just trying to get familiarized with Three.js and came across something strange that I can't quite wrap my head around.

In most other systems, (non web based), that I've used, lighting for normal maps is calculated in tangent space. But in Three.js things are a bit different. For example, if you consider the code in WebGLShaders.js at line 2643:

```
"mat3 tsb = mat3( normalize( vTangent ), normalize( vBinormal ), normalize( vNormal ) );",
"vec3 finalNormal = tsb * normalTex;",
```

they set up the orthonormal basis matrix for tangent space, and then transform the normal into that space. So far so good.

The issue is... that seems to be the only place they transform vectors into tangent space???

So the light direction vector they calculate is not converted to tangent space, and neither is the eye direction vector??? Both of which are subsequently used to calculate the lighting on lines 2692-2694:

```
"vec3 pointHalfVector = normalize( pointVector + viewPosition );",

"float pointDotNormalHalf = max( dot( normal, pointHalfVector ), 0.0 );",

"float pointSpecularWeight = specularTex.r * max( pow( pointDotNormalHalf, uShininess ), 0.0 );",
```

This is a slightly different method of calculating specular than I'm accustomed to. So I was wondering if there was anyone out there able to explain what they are doing? I'd like to have an idea how this shader works so that I can properly translate unity settings when outputting for three.js. That's my ultimate goal.

Answer (score 4):

No. The lighting calculation is being done in camera space.

The `tsb` matrix, which should probably be named `tbn` matrix, transforms the normal from *tangent space* to *camera space*.

You can see for yourself: If the `normalMap` were flat, then `normalTex` would be `( 0, 0, 1 )`, and when you transform that by the `tbn` matrix, you would get the normalized `vNormal` as the result.

three.js r.59